# Force java 7 to only use JDBC 3.0, not JDBC 4.0

Tags: java, jdbc, db2

Well, the title pretty much says it all.

Is there a way to force Java 7 to use JDBC 3.0 and not JDBC 4.0?

I expect the answer is no, but I am hoping...ok, it is more of a hail mary.

Why, you ask, would I want to do such a thing?

Our database is DB2. We use Hibernate.  In the process of moving to Java 7 (finally) we hit this bug:

https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=997798

And, has the next to last line of the last response points out, the fix is in the jdbc3.0 driver (db2jcc) and not in the jdbc4.0 driver (db2jcc4).

Thank you.
Clark.

Comment: How do you add JDBC to the classpath? I'm sure you could change that.

Comment: How Java7 and JDBC are related? If I am not mistaken, JDBC is JEE API right?

Comment: Java 7 includes JDBC 4.1.  It appears that it *only* includes JDBC 4.1 since using a JDBC 3.0 driver results in compiler errors around non-implemented interface methods.

Comment: @ClarkWright: you can't *compile* a JDBC 3 driver with Java 7, but you can definitely *use* a JDBC 3 driver with Java 7.

Comment: @thinksteep: no, JDBC has been a part of Java SE for quite a while now (I think at least since 1.2, but don't quote me on that).

Answer (score 2):

If you put the jdbc3 driver in your classpath instead of the jdbc4 driver, and if you make sure to avoid calling methods existing since JDBC4 in your code, everything should work flawlessly.

Many databases don't support JDBC4 yet, and are usable with Java 7, provided you only call methods supported by the driver.

Comment: When I started this port, that is what I thought.  JDBC 4.1 adds a couple of new methods to old interfaces. One of the things I have always loved about java is that such changes are not backward compatable.  Without the updated driver, the compile phase fails.

Comment: Why would the compile phase fail? Your code doesn't depend on the driver. It depends on the JDBC API.

Comment: @ClarkWright: why are your drivers on the classpath during your compile step? They shouldn't! And if you indeed only use JDBC 3 API calls then working with old drivers in a new JDK works perfectly well! Don't compile with your driver, they are a *pure runtime dependency*!

Answer (score 0):

Put the jdbc3 driver into a folder and write a class loader that only loads from that folder. Use that classloader to load the driver. Then you can use this driver even if your host environment has other ones (i.e. jdbc4) installed. Especially, you have full control over which driver is used.